# Undefined variable niggles

Tags: php

Below is my class. Fig A

```
<?php 

class qcon{
     public static $conn;

function dbcon()
{


     if (!$conn) 
     {
         $host = 'x';
         $username = 'x';
         $password = 'x';
         $dbname = 'x';
         $conn = mysqli_connect($host , $username  , $password ,$dbname);
     }

     return $conn;
}
}


?>
```

Which is called here. Fig B

```
require_once(class file above);
   function openSesame() 
{
$boogey = new qcon();
$conn = $boogey->dbcon();


if (!$conn)
{
    $this->error_msg = "connection error could not connect to the database:! ";  
    return false;
}
$this->conn = $conn;
return true;
}
```

Is causing

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\...\xxxx\figAclass.php on line 10
```

I know I can simply turn errors off, but this seems unwise. I took a look at a generic SO question about the undefined variable notice. Obviously the advice was general - use isset. Had a go at isset and this does not seem correct for what I am trying to do.

Based on the code in figure A and B, is there anything obvious causing the notice to be flagged up. Could you demonstrate a fix that is in line with the existing code shown.

Comment: If you're using a static member, you need to refer it by `self::$conn`

Comment: what is $this in second code... is this part of any class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `if (!$conn)`, which will check to see if the variable is true/false or contains a value, not if it's defined. Use this instead:

```
if(empty($conn))
```

This checks to see if the variable is defined, and if it is NULL/empty.

You also want to use $this->conn inside of your class instead, since you're defining it as a variable of the class.

Comment: actually `if (!$conn)` would be fine here if used correctly (`$this->conn`) as that member always exist.

Comment: Look closely... $conn is declared static.

Comment: $this->conn would exist, yes, but empty would still work because it is does not contain a value.

Comment: @KevinM1 yes, it shouldn't be declared as static.

Comment: @aynber, that's actually debatable... looks like the OP is trying to build a Singleton

Answer (score 1):

when you access it, you should use $this->conn, in example:

```
if(!$this->conn){...}
```

**edited** read the question too fast, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment above, since you have a static `$conn`, you need to refer to it like:

```
public function dbconn()
{
    if (!self::$conn) {
        // blah
    }

    return self::$conn;
}
```

Your error is happening because you're attempting to reference a variable named `$conn`, but due to scope, no such thing exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `if (!$conn)`for this because that will only return 'true' or 'false'.

Use:

`if empty($conn)` instead.